# Динамические мета данные в react + nodejs приложении

Tags: reactjs, node.js

Есть react приложение после загрузки которого, идет запрос на получение данных с бека.
На основе данных нужно менять мета теги, но при вставке/отправки ссылки мета-теги не подгружаются

Comment: Такой ответ тебя устроит? https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.fe488bf0-646dfc63-b70b7ee7-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/questions/58235788/how-to-create-dynamic-meta-tags-from-client-side-in-react-node-js-project

Comment: @ksa не знал что английский SO можно вот так перевести, спасибо :)

Comment: Есть еще такая статейка на тему "Меняем мету прямо на сервере" - https://blog.logrocket.com/adding-dynamic-meta-tags-react-app-without-ssr/

Comment: @ksa спасибо, второй ответ более уместный, но мне он кажется прагматичным

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поднял express сервер на nodejs, проксирую все запросы через nginx на сервер, от сервера отдаю свою самописную верстку, где встраиваю в head билды react приложения